# Python - Coding a formula weaving between + and -

Tags: python, exponent

Apparently

```
-1**2
```

returns a value of `-1` instead of `1`

So I will always receive a negative value. How can I get python to return a positive value for every even exponent?

Comment: Your question title makes me curious what you're going to do with this, since there are more efficient ways to generate alternating terms in a loop than by raising -1 to some power. And even if you want to do it in a list comprehension (or generator expression) you can do `[1-i%2*2 for i in range(5)]` instead of  `[(-1)**i for i in range(5)]`. OTOH, I guess `(-1)**i` is more readable than the technique using `%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-x has lower precedence than **

See for exemple:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm
Therefore:

```
>>> -1**2
-1
>>> (-1)**2
1
```

Comment: PM 2Ring - I understand why this is the case. It takes the exponent and calculates that before factoring in the negative. Thank you Eric, your answer has solved a quarter of my project.

Answer (score 2):

The exponent will be evaluated first and then multiplied by a coefficient of -1.

```
P - Parenthesis
E - Exponents
M - Multiplication
D - and Division
A - Addition
S - and Substraction
```

Comment: Also see [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the official Python docs.